# How to Stop Bubbling on DOMSubtreeModified Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a pretty simple scenario. I have the following HTML:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<input type="button" value="Change" id="change" />
```

With the corresponding JS:

```
var h1 = $("h1").get(0);

h1.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(ev) {

    console.log("Changed");
    
    ev.bubbles = false;
    ev.cancelBubble = true;
    ev.defaultPrevented = true;
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.returnValue = false;
    
    return false;
    
}, false);

$("#change").click(function() {
    $("h1").text("World");
});
```

So, this basically just changes the text of the H1 node and the event is then fired. However, the event is firing twice (as I assume as a result of bubbling). As you can see, I've tried throwing everything at it to try to get it to not fire twice, but that does not stop it. If you want to play with the code, you can check it out at: http://jsfiddle.net/sECtq/. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ev.preventDefault();` will cause IE to throw an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour is not caused by bubbling.

$.text() executes 2 steps to set the new text:

1. remove the existing contents
2. insert a new textNode

Both steps trigger  DOMSubtreeModified, so you get 2 alerts.

You may use e.g. the following:

```
$("h1")[0].firstChild.data="World";
```

This will only change the contents of the textNode without removing a node.

Comment: Doh. Very nice. I had no idea. I'm curious why text uses a 2 step process? I mean, it seems that the sample you have provided condenses this to one step...

Comment: My suggestion assumes that there is only 1 textNode, but jQuery's text() replaces the whole contents(there may be multiple nodes of different kinds). So jQuery first uses his empty()-method to remove those nodes to avoid memory-leaks.

Answer (score 0):

or you can also check whether propagation has been stopped or not. Take a look on the http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped l